# Why is my increment-er returning an object? id_[object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript, forms, function, dynamic

In my form, I want to offer the ability to add another location. It was working when I had only one text box appear,(address) and could get multiple address text boxes to appear. but now I am trying to add the "city" text-box and it is not working.  I used one function before, now I split up my functions to reuse code better.  So now my id's (id_) should be id_1,id_2,ect. but I am getting the object instead.  I think the addLoc() should be on its own, vs **function city()** inside **function addLoc()**, but that wasnt working either.

[image: page source]

HTML

```
<div class="one">
    <button onclick="addLoc()">Add Location</button>
</div>
<div class="three">
    <h2>Locations</h2>
    <form action="#" id="mainform" method="get" name="mainform">
        <div id="myForm"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

javaScript

```
var i = 0; 
  function increment(){
    i += 1; 
  }
function addLoc(){
  var d = document.createElement("DIV");        
  var l = document.createElement("LABEL");      
  var i = document.createElement("INPUT");

  address();    
  city();
  function address() {

    i.setAttribute("type","text");
    i.setAttribute("placeholder","Address");

    build();        
  }
  function build() {            
    var g = document.createElement("IMG");
    g.setAttribute("src", "delete.png");

    increment();
    i.setAttribute("Name","textelement_" + i);
    d.appendChild(l);
    l.setAttribute("for","textelement_" + i);       

    g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm','id_" + i + "')");
    d.appendChild(g);
    d.setAttribute("id","id_" + i);
    document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(d);       
  }
  function city() {     
    i.setAttribute("type","text");
    i.setAttribute("placeholder","City");
    build();
  }
}//end of addLoc()
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jim54729/w27pka3c/) (some changes)

was working fine with just the address text box.  I broke something trying to split up the functions.  I can do it all as one BIG function, but prefer not to.
Any help Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var i = document.createElement("INPUT");` `d.setAttribute("id","id_" + i);` This is why your id is what it is. To fix it, use a different variable name for your input element.

Comment: I forgot I changed that to i, thanks.  That fixes the object issue.  Now I am getting "x"'s to show up instead of the text box, (missing image), but now that I got that far with your help, I will debug again.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you redeclare the variable "i" in your function addLoc() as an input element.  Therefore it's not using the "i" you declared at the top of your code outside the function scope (var i = 0;) on line 0.  So it's actually trying to append the object to the string which turns out as you see it in your html.

Try not to overload variable names, especially when declaring them outside function scope. If you're going to use global variables, preface them with a marker like g_variableName so they don't get mixed up with function scope variables.

Also, try to use meaningful names for your function variables instead of d,l,i.  I would change your input variable them to something like "divElement", "labelElement", "inputElement".

Changing the variable name of 'i' that you declare in the function addLoc() and carrying it through that function should help!

Comment: You are correct, would not have been using "i" twice if I used real names, and i like the idea of g_ for global. I will do that.  It returns the correct value now, just need to spend more time on other issues, but now I can start.  Thanks

Comment: no problem! using real names not only helps you but helps other people who may have to read your code later ;)  if you're worried about program size then you can use a minifier which will obfuscate your code into smaller variable names like a, b, c where it can to save memory.